# drupal_add_js in html template file

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using a zen subtheme and I am trying to add some javascript using the [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)
 on a certain node.
When I use the drupal_add_js from within the **html--node--XX.tpl.php** file, it does not work.

But when I use it in the **page--node--XX.tpl.php** it does. I don't understand what causes the difference in the behavior. I thought that this would be the same.
These are the lines I am adding in both cases:

```
drupal_add_css("sites/all/libraries/shadowbox/shadowbox.css", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE);
drupal_add_js("sites/all/libraries/shadowbox/shadowbox.js", array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 5));
drupal_add_js("Shadowbox.init({skipSetup: true});", array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 6));
```

Can anyone illuminate me here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `drupal_add_js` in a variant of the `html` template will never work, because the styles are printed in the `html` template. At the time you call `drupal_add_js` the variable containing the styles have already been created and you are too late to alter it with `drupal_add_js`.

The reason it works in `page` templates is that it is parsed before the `html` template so the variable containing the styles that is printed in the `html` template has not yet been generated.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. This means that I can use it to page--node--xx.tpl.php or node--xx.tpl.php etc but never on a html.tpl.php variant, right?

Comment: @nikan True. You could do it in a `html.tpl.php` but it would require that you rebuild the `$scripts` variable and did it before it was printed. In other words a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to insert the JS files by the preprocess function in your theme's template.php file:

Here goes an example:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');
}
```

You can use an if() to validate the current path in the $variables in order to prevent the script to be loaded on every page.

To debug the $variables values you can install the devel module an use the dpm() function.

For example:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

Comment: I have tried successfully the preprocess solution for the whole site.  It was in the 'if' part that I got confused. Did not know which variable to check. Still unsure. Normally, in a template I would find the nid from a url argument. Does this work in the template.php file? Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use the `current_path()` function to validate the url to load the script. Like:
`if(current_path() == 'node/X')
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');`

Comment: I suppose you mean `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');`  Yes, this is good! Thanks.

Comment: Exact. Sorry about that. When I realized that I could no longer edit the comment to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Structure is 
html.tpl.php 
->page.tpl.php 
-->node.tpl.php

So it is like html--page--node(--XX).tpl.php

Simply use node--XX.tpl.php but make sure there is a html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php file in your subthemes directory.

Comment: I am confused: you are suggesting that I use three files? I tried using the html--page--node(--XX).tpl.php but it returns a blank page.

Comment: Simply use node--XX.tpl.php and ignore the structure

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add javascript to individual nodes the best option is [Code Per Node](http://drupal.org/project/cpn)

Comment: Useful. Thanks. But in this case I would rather do it through the core drupal functions in the template, than through a module.